# The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML.

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I have migrated the DTS (2005) to SSIS DTSX(2012) and migrated package runs through the SSDT but doesn't run through the Web Application which triggers the SSIS package.

Below is complete error message

***The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.***

I have provided full permission and SET "Run64bitRunTime" to FALSE, still no luck.

**Unfortunately this is not working at Client Server (SQL 2012 SP3 installed) but is working in my development server (SQL 2012 SP3).**

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

VK

Comment: Check [Protection Level] of package and try package movement with a single account (same user credentials in both the boxes).

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to check is the project property Deployment Target Version.   Make sure this is the correct SQL version.   By default it goes to SQL Server VNext.   This was the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

by changing packet runtime from 64 to 32 bit. it should do the trick